# How correctly push data from Logstash to Elasticsearch server?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new in ELK. I need to visualize data from a PostgreSQL in Kibana. I ran into a little problem and need a help.

I use:

1. Elasticsearch 6.4.1
2. Kibana 6.4.1
3. Logstash 6.4.1

When I run next `logstash.conf` file it don't send me correct data to elasticsearch server. What I need to change in my configuration file?

**logstash.conf**:

```
input
{
    jbdc_connection_string => "path_to_database"
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "postgres"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/path_to/postgresql-42.2.5.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT * from documents"
}
output
{
    elasticsearch
    {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "documents"
    }
}
```

Only when in output I use next configuration I see correct data in terminal:

```
strout
{
    codes => json_lines
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say it doesn't send correct data to elasticsearch? Please give some example for getting better help.

Comment: Well, I don't use correct url I guess. When I use `http://localhost:9200/documents/` it show me strange data which looks like system information. Now I tried to use `http://localhost:9200/documents/_search?pretty`. This url show me correct data from database. But I steal have problem. It show me only 5 data however it must me more than 5. What kind of url address I need to use?

Comment: only 5 does not make sense if `"SELECT * from documents"` contains more. maybe is the index mapping conflicting with the logstash output? look at the elasticsearch log, it will yield if some documents get rejected.

Comment: 10 is default size. Anyways try http://localhost:9200/documnets/_search?size=20 to see if you get more documents

Comment: You was right. It show me by default 10 entry. What kind of URL we need to use for pagination?